# How to set runtime configuration in angular after taking production build?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I've used appconfig.json for dynamically obtaining endpoint url's throughout the application using "app_initializer".but the problem here is,if i use json file it is getting exposed in browser window and network tab in developer console because of http get.is there way to hide the json or alternative way to achieve this ? Basically, i need runtime configuration.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

look at dotenv which is use for things like that https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv